# Expo - React Native app crashes in testflight immediately crashes after the splash screen loads

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, apple-developer

I have an expo & react native application that I have build. When developing and testing it, the application runs perfectly on my local machine and simulator as well as my physical devices. I build the application through `eas build --platform ios` and then submitted it to the apple developer account. When I run the application in Testflight, it shows the splash screen and then immediately crashes and throes the crash alert.

The crash log from apple after review displayed the error but I am not sure what is exactly causing the issue. I think it is an npm package but not sure if that is the exact reason.

Stacktrace:

```
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "ktriageinfo" : "VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage\n",
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "lastExceptionBacktrace" : [{"imageOffset":40116,"symbol":"__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":164,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":99280,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":763356,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1231540,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":1233656,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":470020,"symbol":"__invoking___","symbolLocation":148,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":134324,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invoke]","symbolLocation":428,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":132812,"symbol":"-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]","symbolLocation":64,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":958332,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":967008,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":966120,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":8992,"symbol":"_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":32,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":16044,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":46388,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain","symbolLocation":668,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":49316,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":93404,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":3548,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":2940,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":12}],
  "faultingThread" : 1,
  "threads" : [{"id":460443,"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":3204,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":80724,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":81452,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":540,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":4552,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":127500,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply","symbolLocation":548,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":128412,"symbol":"dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":66072,"symbol":"xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync","symbolLocation":240,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":10697388,"symbol":"-[GEOXPCRequest sendSync:error:]","symbolLocation":232,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4833572,"symbol":"_GEOGetAllValuesInStore","symbolLocation":196,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4069504,"symbol":"-[GEOConfigStorageCached resync]","symbolLocation":80,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":4068996,"symbol":"-[GEOConfigStorageCached getConfigValueForKey:countryCode:options:source:]","symbolLocation":176,"imageIndex":6}
```

Here is the device that it was tested on:

```
"uptime" : 65000,
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad11,6",
  "coalitionID" : 1277,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 16.5.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "20F75"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-06-30 12:58:50.2801 -0700",
  "incident" : "BF86938B-5562-4A8C-B058-1C2DDC77BEDB",
  "pid" : 2981,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2023-06-30 12:58:50.0089 -0700",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 1560679672274,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 1560686110050,
  "procName" : "Rippe",
  "procPath" : "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/5191B255-ACE4-4921-83C5-49AD676CEF8F\/Rippe.app\/Rippe",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.0","CFBundleVersion":"1","CFBundleIdentifier":"app.rippeapp.com","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14E221"},
  "storeInfo" : {"itemID":"6450795147","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"A0B69947-7299-465C-AB19-355D955F323D","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"858167359"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "app.rippeapp.com",
  "crashReporterKey" : "b3ddb8582d3b8e5e8ba255ff7366f65d3c1291b8",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "codeSigningID" : "app.rippeapp.com",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "6R56DDHA5N",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570450689,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 4,
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.3.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.15.2",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
    "expo": "~48.0.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "patch-package": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-email": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-email-link": "^1.14.5",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: `react-native-vector-icons` should not be used with Expo. Use official Expo Icons package optimized for Expo - https://docs.expo.dev/guides/icons/#expovector-icons